# does IE 6,7 support background-color:inherit; for CSS?

Tags: css, inheritance

A quick question:

Does IE 6,7 support the css of

```
background-color:inherit;
```

?

for example

```
<li>
  <a ='/'></a>
</li>

a {
  background-color:inherit;
}
```

Will IE 6/7 use the background color of 'li' element for 'a' element?

Comment: Why not simply have the `a` background set to `transparent`?

Comment: Does transparent also work in ie 6/7?

Comment: I believe so, but I'd have to check to be sure.

Comment: Just for the record, `transparent` is NOT supported by IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not work in IE 6 or 7 and will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer <= 7   versions don’t support the value `inherit` for any properties other than `direction` and `visibility`.